# SQL Validating a string variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Scripts, I need to validate Comma Separate value. How should i validate the String Variable ?

Validation should be both Right / Left Trim for each value and there should not be any special characters such as Comma or Period for the last value.

```
 create table #test
 (col varchar(100))

 insert into #test values
 ('1,2'),
 ('1,2,'),
 ('1,'),
 ('1,2,3,4,5')


 select * from #test
```

In the above query, for the second value - Expected Result is 1,2
In the above query, for the Third value - Expected Result is 1

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"validate from SQL"*? Do you need an SQL that returns all invalid values? Or all valid ones? Or an extra field indicating whether the name is valid or not?

Comment: @Heinzi, i have edited my posting with clear explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your table to fix "offensive" values.

```
update #test
set col = substring(col, 1, len(col) - 1)
where col not like '%[0-9]'
```

This will remove last character where value doesn't end by a digit.

Comment: Your syntax logic helps me. This resolves the data issue, I can tweak it according to my needs. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Will you please help me in this posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37766643/sql-compare-varchar-variable-with-another-varchar-variable

Answer (score 1):

You can use a check constraint.  You seem to want something like this:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_name as
    (name like '%,%' and
     name not like '%,%,%' and
     name not like '%[^a-zA-Z,]%'
    )
```

SQL Server doesn't have support for regular expressions.  This implements the rules:

- Name has to have a comma
- Name does not have two commas
- Name consists only of alphabetic characters and a comma

You may find that you need slightly more flexibility, but this handles the cases in your question.

Comment: i cant alter the table. I have to work on the data part.  database belongs to third party.

Comment: @goofyui . . . You can use the same logic in a `where` or `case`.  Your question states that you want to validate data and that is what a check constraint does.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, Not sure whether i was able to get it. I tried with sample query, it didnt work. I have posted a Sample Temp table query in the original posting. Please take a look.