# SQL Compare varchar variable with another varchar variable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Table name lines which has BillId (int) and LineReference (Varchar(100) as two columns. Each billid has LineReference value. However, value in the LineReference might not be correct. So i have to validate the LineReference from a variable which has already has correct Reference value based on the bill id.

Example :

```
Declare @iCountRef varchar(100) = 1,2,3

BillId   LineReference
100      1,2,
100      1,2,40,34
100      1
100      12
```

From the above table, I need to update the LineReference column.

```
BillId   LineReference
100      1,2
100      1,2
100      1
100      1
```

I would be able to update only by comparing with the variable : @iCountRef. LineReference column should have the values in the @iCountRef. Whatever values are not there in @CountRef should be removed. If there is no matching values,then the column should be updated atleast with number 1.

Comment: Is sequence is mandatory when comparing reference value from 1,2,3 or may 3,2,1  ?

Comment: I never thought about sequence issue. I need to get this query as close as possible. please help me.

Comment: the above @iCountRef  character always will be hard coded known characters 1,2,3?

Comment: Nope, that value is dynamic.  - That value is populated from a function. Inside that function , I am running a select query for each id.  value is dynamic.  It can be only one. or 1,2. or,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10  or more than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
--Create temp table and inserting data:
DECLARE @BillsRefs TABLE (
    BillId int, 
    LineReference nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @BillsRefs VALUES
(100,      '1,2,'),
(100,      '1,2,40,34'),
(100,      '1'),
(100,      '12')

--Declare variables
DECLARE @iCountRef varchar(100) = '1,2,3',
        @xml xml, @iXml xml

--Convert @iCountRef in XML
SELECT @iXml = CAST('<b>' + REPLACE(@iCountRef,',','</b><b>') + '</b>' as xml)

--@iXml:
--<b>1</b>
--<b>2</b>
--<b>3</b>

--Convert table with data in XML
SELECT @xml = (
SELECT CAST('<s id="'+LineReference+'"><a>' + REPLACE(LineReference,',','</a><a>') + '</a></s>' as xml) 
FROM @BillsRefs
FOR XML PATH('')
)
--@xml:
--<s id="1,2,">
--  <a>1</a>
--  <a>2</a>
--  <a />
--</s>
--<s id="1,2,40,34">
--  <a>1</a>
--  <a>2</a>
--  <a>40</a>
--  <a>34</a>
--</s>
--<s id="1">
--  <a>1</a>
--</s>
--<s id="12">
--  <a>12</a>
--</s>

--Compare values from temp table to @iCountRef
--we convert string to xml - to convert them intoi tables
;WITH final AS (
SELECT DISTINCT
        t.v.value('../@id','nvarchar(100)') as LineReferenceOld, -- @id to take 'id="1,2,40,34"' from xml above
        CASE WHEN s.g.value('.','int') IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE s.g.value('.','int') END as LineReference 
        -- '.' is used to take value inside closed tags
FROM @xml.nodes('/s/a') as t(v) --we takes @xml (look above) and play with its nodes 's' (root for each @id) and `a`
LEFT JOIN @iXml.nodes('/b') as s(g) --we takes @iXml it has only 'b' tags
    ON t.v.value('.','int') = s.g.value('.','int') --here we JOIN both xml by `a` and `b`  tags
)

--In final table we get this:

--LineReferenceOld  LineReference
--1,2,              2
--12                    1
--1,2,40,34         1
--1,2,40,34         2
--1                 1
--1,2,              1

--Final SELECT
SELECT c.BillId,
        STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT  ','+CAST(f.LineReference as nvarchar(10))
        FROM final f
        WHERE c.LineReference = f.LineReferenceOld
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as LineReference
FROM @BillsRefs c
```

Output:

```
BillId  LineReference
100     1,2
100     1,2
100     1
100     1
```

If you need to update source table:

```
UPDATE c
SET LineReference = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT  ','+CAST(f.LineReference as nvarchar(10))
        FROM final f
        WHERE c.LineReference = f.LineReferenceOld
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
FROM @BillsRefs c
```

Comment: thanks a lot. i see 1 is updated for no match. for making null for no match, what i have to do. i need two different syntax ..!!

Comment: just finding hard to understand your syntax. if i have to keep NULL for no match, i am not able to change your syntax. Please help me to understand .. your syntax. Thanks

Comment: Hi! I add some explanation - please check. I suggest you to read about xml nodes on MSDN

Comment: In the BillRef table.. There might be values such as 1a,2a for the LineReference Column. Which needs to be handled. I see, INT data type is defined. I am working on it to handle all scenarios. Thanks

Comment: Then add this example to your question and add info about how to handle this situation. As fast workaround replace all 'int' to 'nvarchar(10)' in 'final' cte.

Answer (score 4):

1) On medium or long term I would like to normalize this database in order to avoid such mistakes: storing list of values within string/VARCHAR columns. For example, I would use following many to many table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.BillItem (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    BilldID INT NOT NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Bill(BilldID),
    ItemID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Item(ItemID),
    UNIQUE (BillID, ItemID) -- Unique constraint created in order to prevent duplicated rows
);
```

In this case, one bill with two items means I have to insert two rows into `dbo.BillItem` table.

2) Back to original request: for one time task I would use XML and XQuery thus (this solution ends with a SELECT statement but it's trivial to convert into UPDATE):

```
DECLARE @iCountRef VARCHAR(100) = '1,2,3'

DECLARE @SourceTable TABLE (
    BillId          INT,
    LineReference   VARCHAR(8000)
)

INSERT @SourceTable (BillId, LineReference)
VALUES
(100, '1,2,'),
(100, '1,2,40,34'),
(100, '1'),
(100, '12')

DECLARE @iCountRefAsXML XML = CONVERT(XML, '<a><b>' + REPLACE(@iCountRef, ',', '</b><b>') + '</b></a>')

SELECT  *, STUFF(z.LineReferenceAsXML.query('
    for $i in (x/y)
        for $j in (a/b)
            where data(($i/text())[1]) eq data(($j/text())[1])
        return concat(",", ($i/text())[1])
').value('.', 'VARCHAR(8000)'), 1, 1, '') AS NewLineReference
FROM (
    SELECT  *, CONVERT(XML, 
        '<x><y>' + REPLACE(LineReference, ',', '</y><y>') + '</y></x>' + 
        '<a><b>' + REPLACE(@iCountRef, ',', '</b><b>') + '</b></a>'
    ) AS LineReferenceAsXML
    FROM    @SourceTable s
) z
```

Results:

```
BillId      LineReference  NewLineReference LineReferenceAsXML                                                      
----------- -------------  ---------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------
100         1,2,           1 ,2             <x><y>1</y><y>2</y><y /></x><a><b>1</b><b>2</b><b>3</b></a>             
100         1,2,40,34      1 ,2             <x><y>1</y><y>2</y><y>40</y><y>34</y></x><a><b>1</b><b>2</b><b>3</b></a>
100         1              1                <x><y>1</y></x><a><b>1</b><b>2</b><b>3</b></a>                          
100         12             (null)           <x><y>12</y></x><a><b>1</b><b>2</b><b>3</b></a>
```

Comment: If you have any questions / doubts then feel free to ask.

Comment: Amazing ..!!! I honor your help ..!! Thanks a lot ..!!! One small alteration.. i request you.. we are adding number : 1 , if there is no match. If i have to update it as NULL, instead of no match.. is it hard to do that ??

Comment: @goofyui: See updated answer. I removed `ISNULL(..., '1') function`. Now, if there is no match it returns NULL.

Comment: thanks a lot .. but will it be possible to have only billid and linereference column .. ( i will be updating  the linereference column ) with new data. Present query has xml column also.. which i am not able to remove it.

Comment: @goofyui: $i and $j = items from (x/y) and (a/b) collections = they are XML elements which have inner text -> {$i|$j}/text() returns the inner text of current XML ($i or $j) element.